# For Transcoding HTTP/JSON to gRPC, how to specify query parameter for empty message?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, envoyproxy, proto

I have a request message in our proto file with definition similar to below

```
rpc GetBookUploadUrl (GetBookUploadUrlRequest) returns (GetBookUploadUrlResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/bookstore/v1/books/upload-url"
    };
}
```

The request message looks like this:

```
message GetBookUploadUrlRequest{
...
    BookFormat format = 2;
... 
}

message BookFormat{
    oneof book_format {
        PDF pdf = 1;
        Image image = 2;
        Text text = 3;
        ...
    }   
}

message PDF{
    // empty message
}

message Text{
    int lines = 1;
}
```

Now, while calling the http endpoint using format as text works perfectly well

```
GET /bookstore/v1/books/upload-url?format.text.lines=100
```

But this doesn't work

```
GET /bookstore/v1/books/upload-url?format.pdf=
```

I suspect it is because the PDF message is empty.
Does anyone has idea how to pass the empty message in query parameter?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. I used POST instead.